# whenever i try to run this code it gives me an error

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class one
{
    int r;
public:
    one(int a) : r(a) {}
    void set(int a) { r = a; }
    int area() { return r*r*3.14; }
};

class two
{
    one x;
    int hi;
public:
    two(int r, int h)
    {
        hi=h;
        x.set(r);
    }

    int v() { return x.area()*hi; }
};

int main()
{
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

> the error is:no appropriate default constructer available.
>   would you mind helping me so that i can get rid of this error.
>   //.............................................................................

Comment: `one` doesn't declare a default constructor using any parameters. Try replacing `one x;` with something like `one x(0);`.

Comment: Make it `two(int r, int h) : x(r), hi(h) {}`. Then read about [constructor initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) in your favorite C++ textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `x` in `two`, C++ basically tries to create an instance of one using a constructor without any parameters (default constructor), since "null objects" do not exist in C++.

one does not provide a default constructor, but it provides the constructor `one(int a)`, so instead of `one x;`, use `one x(0);` or `one x = one(0);`